# UIWebView width 0

Tags: uiviewcontroller, uiwebview, ios6, ios4

The code part:

```
UIWebView *wb = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
self.examplesView = wb;
[wb release];
examplesView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
[self.view addSubview:examplesView];
NSLog(@"createViewsForRect: %@, examplesView.frame : %@",NSStringFromCGRect(rect), NSStringFromCGRect(examplesView.frame));
```

The output:

> createViewsForRect: {{0, 0}, {320, 480}}, examplesView.frame : {{0,
>   0}, {0, 0}}

This UIViewController is added later to another controller, where is called a function to load something and I did a log:

> examplesView.frame: {{0, 0}, {0, 360}}

Because the width is 0 that's why isn't visible. How to fix it? Why is getting 0 width?

This is an old, inherited code without ARC...

Comment: `rect` is neither defined nor used in the code above, it there a typo? Or what you want is `UIWebView *wb = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];`?

Comment: it is defined in the function header, it is true: it isn't used later in function! That solve my question, please write as answer to accept it1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first line shall be

```
UIWebView *wb = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
```

then `wb` will be initialized with the frame you want.

Comment: you gave the correct answer, but in my code I need a: examplesView.frame = rect; That was missing